# react-native navigation(v5) deepLinking get params from URL

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, deep-linking, react-navigation-v5

**Have any ideas  how can I get correct params ?**

I getting this **URL** and I want navigate to correct screen within correct params.

URL -> /p-einhell-drill-screwdriver-123456/

I want to take form that url 3 parameters:

1. URL which is -> p-einhell-drill-screwdriver-123456/
2. seoName -> einhell-drill-screwdriver
3. id -> 123456

I can take all of them in one parameter but i can not spread in 3 param.
At this moment I have this parser but It takes only one params.

Forxample:

```
const config = {
     ProductScreen: {
                       path: ':seoName/',   /* p-einhell-drill-screwdriver-123456/ */
                       parse: {
                          seoName: (seoName) =>
                             seoName.split('-').slice(1, -1).join('-'),
                          URL: (seoName) => seoName,
                          currentProductId: (seoName) =>
                             seoName.split('-').pop(),
                       },
                    },
}
```

**Result:**

> ```
>   params: {
>
>   URL: undefined
>
>   currentProductId: undefined
>
>   seoName: "einhell-drill-screwdriver"    }
> ```

Answer (score 1):

The options under `parse` refer to the params defined in the config (e.g. `:seoName`) and query params if any. You can't add arbitrary properties there.

But you can return an object in `seoName`:

```js
parse: {
  seoName: URL => {
    const seoName = URL.split('-').slice(1, -1).join('-');
    const currentProductId = URL.split('-').pop();

    return { URL, seoName, currentProductId };
  }
}
```

And then get this object in `route.params.seoName` in your component.

Comment: thank you, I done it already but I was trying to find new ways.